# UITableViewCells bleeding off bottom and disappearing

Tags: swift, uitableview

My tableview cells are only showing 3 out of 4 in my last section. Decreasing their height, more appear. Increasing the row height, less appear.

My height for row at index path:

return 64

and my tableview is created:

```
lazy var performanceTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
        tableView.separatorStyle = .None
        tableView.scrollEnabled = true
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundColor()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        return tableView
    }()
```

my tableview cells seem to stop at the bottom, like my view height is limited, stuck to a frame.. any idea why?

Comment: Replace this tableView.frame = self.view.bounds with  tableView.frame = self.view.frame

Answer (score 0):

UITableView `clipsToBounds` property is set to `true` by default. You may want to change that if you're looking for the cells to continue through the bottom of the view's frame.

Additionally, set the tableview's frame to the view's frame, or create constraints to bind this view to the edges.